# Check Main Key value under which the sub array is grouped

Tags: javascript

I had an array and I grouped them on the category id using _groupBy and got the array as below.

```
{
"cat1":[
        {"id":"1","name":"SomeName", "category":"cat1"},
        {"id":"15","name":"SomeName2", "category":"cat1"}
    ],
"cat2":[
        {"id":"12","name":"Somename3", "category":"cat2"}
    ],
"cat3":[
        {"id":"18","name":"SomeName4", "category":"cat3"}
    ]
}
```

How to check the main group under which they are grouped. So I can render the cat2 first and then the other categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.keys()` returns all enumerable keys of an object.

You can also use `Object.entries()` which gives you an array where each item is `[key, value]` of a given object.

```js
const data = {
"cat1":[
        {"id":"1","name":"SomeName", "category":"cat1"},
        {"id":"15","name":"SomeName2", "category":"cat1"}
    ],
"cat2":[
        {"id":"12","name":"Somename3", "category":"cat2"}
    ],
"cat3":[
        {"id":"18","name":"SomeName4", "category":"cat3"}
    ]
}

const delayed = [];

for(const [name, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
  if (name === "cat2") {
    console.log(value); // first log cat2
    continue;
  }
  delayed.push(value); // the rest will be put to delayed array
}

delayed.forEach(console.log.bind(console)); // log remaining items
```

Another way is to use object destructuring to pluck `cat2` from object, use it first and then do whatever you want with the rest:

```js
const { cat2, ...rest } = obj;
```